# executing a program using PHP

Tags: php, shell, command

I want to execute a simulation program in PHP which is already installed the pc root. that means, I can execute it in any directory. I tried to execute it using shell_exec but I cant see any output, while when I run it from terminal it works anywhere. this program also will generate an image which later I want it to appear in the page which is not a big deal. but the problem is there is just an empty image created and no output values.

```
<?php
$output = exec('rpict -vp 0 0 0 -vd 0.01 0 1 -ab 2 -ad 2048 -ar 64 -as 64 -aa 0.1 -vv 180 -vh 180 -vth with_sun_12_30_13_30.oct > test.hdr'); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
?>
```

Comment: please update your question with the code you have tried, the WAMP server your using and also check your error log for clues.

Comment: Are you echoing the shell_exec output?  It returns it, it doesn't echo itself.  Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` if you still can't see output.

Comment: <?
$output = exec('rpict -vp 0 0 0 -vd 0.01 0 1 -ab 2 -ad 2048 -ar 64 -as 64 -aa 0.1 -vv 180 -vh 180 -vth with_sun_12_30_13_30.oct > test.hdr');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>

Comment: this is the code I am using! I also tried shell_exec instead of exec and passthru but non one them works.

Comment: the error I get is 30711. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `rpict` isn't on the path of the user running the web server. Try replacing it with the full path. (You can find this by typing `which rpict` on most systems).

Like Devon says, turn error reporting up too, to make sure you're getting the full picture:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $output = shell_exec('/path/to/rpict ...');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: still not working, is it possible that I cannot communicate with my directories?
in the terminal for instance if I use just rvu command, it will return:
 rvu: fatal - missing octree argument
but I dont get any output and now only 30711 appears.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with radiance, I'm afraid, but it sounds like the problem does not lie within your PHP code. Which user is the web server running under? (On a Debian (etc) box, this is usually www-data)

Comment: I am running an Apache web server. Radiance is added to the root directory, so can be run in any folder, but if you are addressing a text file or image directory is important. I have another possibility as I am good in matlab, I can easily do all this steps in matlab code, only think which I should consider is to run the matlab m file from php which I hope its easier than Radiance.

Comment: If you run `which rpict` on the server, what do you get back? Just to double check PHP can definitely find it. Running either command from PHP should be trivial, so long as it can find everything it needs.

Comment: I get /usr/bin/, I also tried to add the path behin the command which looks like this:
$output= shell_exec('/usr/bin/rpict ....');
but didnt work also.

Comment: Did you get an error message from PHP, or did it fail silently?